# How to insert an integer after each digit in an integer value

Tags: java

Hi I have an integer value as `1234`.

Now I want to insert programatically an integer like `3` before each digit in my integer value .

So I want final result as `31323334`.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: I don't get your final result, and how it relates to `1234`?

Comment: First starting point: use `String.valueOf` to get the string representation. You've then changed the problem to "how can I insert a new character before each character in an existing string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Java 8`

**Code**:

```
   int number = 1234;

   //convert int to a list
   List<String> list = Arrays.asList(String.valueOf(number).split(""));

   //add 3 to each elements of the list and derive a String list as the result
   List<String> listContain3 = list.stream()
                                   .map( i -> "3"+i)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());

   //add all elements of the list together and convert it to the int 
   int result =  Integer.parseInt(String.join("", listContain3));

   System.out.println(result);
```

**Output**:

```
31323334
```

Answer (score 3):

How to do it.

1. convert the `integer` to `String`
2. `String` to `char array`
3. declare new `char array` `double` of src `char array` size
4. `Iterate` over `char array`
5. insert into new array and 3 before every `char`.
6. `char array` to `String` and `String` to `integer`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion.

Use `StringBuilder`

First append your `1234` to `StringBuilder`. Then use a `for` loop to insert `3`

You can use  `stringBuilder.insert(i,"3");` to add element to specific location, `i` is the index and "`3`" is the inserting `String`.

Then `stringBuilder.toString()` will give you the result.

Answer (score 0):

Not that playing with strings won't work but there is a fun mathy way to do it:

```
    final int x = 1234;
    int a = 0;  //answer
    int s = 1;  //source
    int o = 1;  //old source 
    int d = 1;  //destination

    do 
    {
        o = s;
        s *= 10; 
        a += x % s / o * d;  //00000004  copy one digit from x to a
        d *= 10;
        a += 3 * d;          //00000034  copy a three
        d *= 10;
    }
    while (s < x);

    System.out.println("a = " + a);
```

prints a = 31323334